# How can I make Python recognize an asterisk in a cell of my DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, escaping

So, I have a DataFrame which in some cells presents an asterisk rather than a figure. I would like to build a function that spots the asterisks in the cells and substitutes them with a 0.
This is what I was thinking about:

```
def clean(row):
    if 's' in str(row):
        return re.sub(r's', '', str(row))

    elif '*' in str(row):
        return re.sub('*','' , str(row))

    else:
        return row
```

but it is clear that I need some expression to escape the '*' and have Python recognize it as the object I want to substitute. The part of interest in the function here is of course the "elif" one.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add a couple of examples of the actual strings you are expecting to have in the "row" variable?

Comment: Here row is not a variable, it stands for the row itself. This way if I apply this function to a column of a DataFrame it will skim through the rows and check for what I told him to check.

Comment: This is what I have:

   Torino  Milano Genova
0      10      15      *

this is what I would like to achieve:

   Torino  Milano Genova
0      10      15      0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're searching for backslash.

\ Backslash, turns off the special meaning of the next character.

```
import re


def clean(row):
    if 's' in str(row):
        return re.sub(r's', '', str(row))

    elif '*' in str(row):
        return re.sub(r'\*', '', str(row))

    else:
        return row


row = "ij*efs"
print(row, clean(row))
```

In case, if you want to replace every asterisk in Dataframe , u can use 
`df.replace()` method.

`df.replace(to_replace=r'\*', value='', regex=True)`

Comment: This does not work on the DataFrames I tried on. If you try to build a small DataFrame (in excel and the import it) with two rows and three columns named after three cities, let's say SF, NYC, LA and in the second row you put 4,6,* you will notice that my code but also the one with the backslash does not work. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @GuidoBongioanni it's pandas dataframe?

Comment: @GuidoBongioanni pls, show, how you getting rows from dataframe.

Comment: yes @IlyaDatskevich it is a pandas dataframe. I think I don't understand what you mean by saying how you getting rows from your dataframe. 

`import pandas as pd`
`#import numpy as np`
`import os`
`import re`

`os.chdir(r'mypath')`


`wow = pd.read_excel('wow.xlsx')`
`wowdf= pd.DataFrame(wow)`
`def clean(row):`
`    if 's' in str(row):`
`        return re.sub(r's', '', str(row))`
    
`    elif '*' in str(row):`
`        return re.sub('\*','' , str(row))`
    
`    else:`
 `       return row`
    
    
wowdf['Genova'].apply(clean)`

Comment: @GuidoBongioanni check update in answer. If it's not suitable for you, let me know.

Comment: wonderful. The expression you added to your first answer worked!

Comment: @GuidoBongioanni in your example you transform `pandas.Series` into string, to replace what you need, but it's not right approach, because u can't transform string into `pandas.Series` correctly for using `.apply` method.